# What could be the reason for fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am using Python 3.7 (64-bit) and installed **cx_Freeze** for converting .py into .exe.

I used this command prompt to convert Python script into an executable:

```
python [filename] build
```

It successfully build the executable. But when I executed my EXE file, I just get output:

> fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec
>   ImportError: invalid flags 1530052318 in 'encoding'
>   Current thread 0X000013f8 :

How to solve it and successfully make an executable file using **cx_Freeze**?

Comment: I get the same error. Try using Python 3.6 (32-bit).

Comment: The issue [#399](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/399) was opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in [4c18633](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/4c18633ba2331d980f00aff075f17135399c43c5).
The problem is that for version x64 for Python 3.7 it is not working due to class config for `freezer.py`.
You need to go `cx_Freezer` installation folder. If you have a virtual environment, go to your environment folder `\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze`,
find the `freezer.py` and add the code found on the commit.

You can find the patch at
[GitHub](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/4c18633ba2331d980f00aff075f17135399c43c5)