# How do I fix an Error when Freezing Python 3.7 Script using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, python-3.7, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a standalone executable with my python script using cx_Freeze.
This is the error I am getting: `error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\tcl\\tcl8.6'`

Does this have anything to do with using a module such as PySimpleGUI? I am using `PySimpleGUI 3.1.2`.

How do I fix this?

Here is my code ([setup.py and Track_Companion.py](https://github.com/kelle1/Track-Companion)).

`Note: Track_Companion.py is not yet finished.`

Comment: The only way I've created an EXE using PySimpleGUI is by using PyInstaller as shown in the readme.  Side note... I would upgrade your PySimpleGUI. It's at 3.14.0 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instructions for making .EXE files from programs using PySimpleGUI can be found in the docs [here](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/#creating-a-windows-exe-file).

To create the .EXE:

> pyinstaller -wF yoursourcefile.py

I would upgrade your PySimpleGUI package prior to doing it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `cx_Freeze` does not yet support Python 3.7, it has a bug. A bugfix exists but has not yet been released, however you can apply it manually, see [What could be the reason for fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51183280/8516269) and [Cx_freeze crashing Python3.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314105/8516269). Or you can rollback to Python 3.6 if this is an option for you.
2. Have you checked that `C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\tcl\\tcl8.6` exists? It would anyway be better to let your setup script dynamically determine you Python installation directory using `PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))` as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034479/8516269).
3. You need to tell `cx_Freeze` to include the Tcl and Tk DLLs using the `build_exe` option `include_files` as done in [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43034479/8516269); if you are using `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1 or 5.1.0, you need to do it slightly differently, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257858/8516269).