# cx_Freeze missing module

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm using python 3.7 and cx_Freeze 5.1.1 , I'm, trying to convert my python script into an executable but I am getting thrown a missing module error and I am stumped.

I have tried putting the modules in the package and includes of the setup script but nothing is changing.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
# build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "win32api", "win32con", "pywintypes", "easyguy", "ntsecuritycon"
#    , "win32security", "errno", "shutil", "ctypes"], "excludes": ["tkinter"],
#                     "includes" = ['easy_gui']}

build_exe_options = {'packages': ['sys', "os", "win32api", "win32con", 
                                  "pywintypes", "easygui", "ntsecuritycon",
                                  "errno", "shutil", "ctypes", "win32security", 
                                  "errno", "shutil", "ctypes"],
                     'excludes': ['tkinter'],
                     'includes': ["os", "win32api", "win32con", "pywintypes", 
                                  "easygui", "ntsecuritycon",
                                  "errno", "shutil", "ctypes", "win32security", 
                                  "errno", "shutil", "ctypes"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="Automated Installer",  # this will set the name of the created executable to "Automated Installer.exe"
      version="0.1",
      description="My GUI application!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("Automated Installer.py", base=base)])  # this tells cx_Freeze to freeze the script "Automated Installer.py"
```

I expect a executable to be created, instead I am thrown this error\

```
ImportError: No module named 'win32api'
```

**EDIT 2: Reflecting Steps taken by the answer posted below.**

I upgraded back to Python 3.7 and I applied the fix to freezer.py as recommended. I took the exact same easygui script written and the same setup.py script also written below. The executable builds, but does not run. I am thrown an error shown below. I am able to run the example easygui script just fine, so that leads me to believe that easygui is installed correctly.

[image: Error popup when executable created is run]

I'm not too sure what you mean by the full stack trace but here is some notable output from the command prompt that I received

```
Missing modules:
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb 
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, 
importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform
? easygui imported from hello world__main__
? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, tracemalloc, unittest, 
unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from http.server, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? termios imported from tty
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this 
platform.

running build
running build_exe
copying C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-                                        
packages\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe -> build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\hello 
world.exe
copying 
C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\python37.dll
copying 
C:\Users\Billy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\VCRUNTIME140.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\VCRUNTIME140.dll
copying C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll - 
> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
copying C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
copying C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
copying C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
copying C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll -> 
build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
*** WARNING *** unable to create version resource
install pywin32 extensions first
writing zip file build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\lib\library.zip
```

Comment: I'v tried to fix the indentation of your code, can you please confirm that it is correct now, or fix further? You still have unnecessary entries in the `build_exe` options.

Answer (score 1):

1. `cx_Freeze` does not yet support Python 3.7, it has a bug. A bugfix exists but has not yet been released, however you can apply it manually, see [What could be the reason for fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51183280/8516269) and [Cx_freeze crashing Python3.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314105/8516269). Or you can rollback to Python 3.6 if this is an option for you.

EDIT:

2. Check that `easygui` is correctly installed. You should for example be able to run the following `hello.py` example script from the `easygui` [documentation](https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#easygui-s-demonstration-routine):

   ```py
   from easygui import *
   import sys

   # A nice welcome message
   ret_val = msgbox("Hello, World!")
   if ret_val is None: # User closed msgbox
       sys.exit(0)

   msg = "What is your favorite flavor?\nOr Press <cancel> to exit."
   title = "Ice Cream Survey"
   choices = ["Vanilla", "Chocolate", "Strawberry", "Rocky Road"]
   while 1:
       choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)
       if choice is None:
           sys.exit(0)
       msgbox("You chose: {}".format(choice), "Survey Result")
   ```
3. Try to freeze this example script. `easygui` depends on `tkinter`, which requires some additional tuning to be frozen with `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1, see [tkinter program compiles with cx_Freeze but program will not launch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52785654/8516269). You should be able to freeze the example using the following setup script:

   ```py
   from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
   import os
   import sys

   PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
   os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
   os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

   build_exe_options = {'include_files': [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                                           os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll')),
                                          (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                                           os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll'))]}

   # GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
   # console application).
   base = None
   if sys.platform == 'win32':
       base = 'Win32GUI'

   setup(name='hello',
         version='0.1',
         description='Sample cx_Freeze EasyGUI script',
         executables=[Executable('hello.py', base=base)],
         options={'build_exe': build_exe_options})
   ```

Comment: I made a simpler setup.py that has only easygui as part of includes and packages, and I rolled back my python to 3.6.8. When I ran python setup.py build, I still got `ImportError: No module named 'easygui'`

Comment: @BChiu I've edited my answer accordingly. If you still have problems with this example, please post the complete error message including the full stack trace.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the differences between includes and packages are in my original setup.py, Is there anything wrong with my setup,py that could lead to an missing module error? I have adjusted the original question to reflect the current steps I have taken. I also noted that you don't have a packages option in your `build_exe_options`

Comment: @BChiu As far as the difference between `includes` and `packages` is concerned, see the `cx_Freeze` [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe). I'm able to run the example script of my answer frozen with the setup script of my answer with python 3.6 and `cx_Freeze` 5.1.1. Try to rollback to python 3.6 and upgrade all packages to the latest version. If it still does not work I unfortunately don't know how to help further.

Comment: @BChiu Maybe try to add `'packages': ['tkinter', 'easygui']` to the `build_exe_options` dictionary.

Comment: @BChiu One more question: are you using the **same** python installation to run the unfrozen script and to freeze it with `cx_Freeze`?