# cx_Freeze Python Executable error - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, cx-freeze, timedelta

My code works perfectly fine when executed from IDLE. I used cx_Freeze to compile my python code into an executable application and now it wont run. I've added my "setup.py" code below. I have also provided the result of running the program from command prompt.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\tcl\tk8.6'

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy"]}

setup(name= 'Current-Translator',
      version = '1.0',
      description = 'Convert and plot electrical current data from data logger.',
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [Executable('Current-Translator.py')])
```

Command Prompt Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Current-Translator.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\timedelta\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    @public.add
  File "C:\Users\jchoujaa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\public\__init__.py", line 65, in add
    return _add(_caller_modules()[1], objects)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please post the error message with full stack trace (command prompt output) as text, not as an image. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use the following `build_exe` options in your setup script:

   ```
   build_exe_options = {"packages": ["numpy", "public", "timedelta"]}
   ```
2. It seems like you are using `cx_Freeze` with python 3.7, apparently without further problem. `cx_Freeze` does not yet support Python 3.7, it has a bug (for some system configurations only?). A bugfix exists but has not yet been released, however you can apply it manually, see [What could be the reason for fatal python error:initfsencoding:unable to load the file system codec?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51183280/8516269) and [Cx_freeze crashing Python3.7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51314105/8516269). Or you can rollback to Python 3.6 if this is an option for you.

Comment: I tried adding the 'build_exe' options, no luck there. Probably would have more luck using python 3.6.